# How do I create a histogram of duration of NaN intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, histogram, nan

I have a large dataframe indexed by datetimes (consecutive 1min data), with lots of NaN.

I would like to generate a histogram for the occurence of NaNs as a function of the length of the interval of NaNs (for example the x-axis would be the size in days of the NaN "holes" and the y-axis the counts for that specific hole).

Suppose my data looks like this:

```
2015-01-01 05:57:00     2.136221
2015-01-01 05:58:00     4.101965
2015-01-01 05:59:00     NaN
2015-01-01 06:00:00     8.082413
2015-01-01 06:01:00     9.035858
2015-01-01 06:02:00    10.059280
2015-01-01 06:03:00    11.143933
2015-01-01 06:04:00    12.281069
2015-01-01 06:05:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:06:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:07:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:08:00    16.925832
2015-01-01 06:09:00    18.150440
2015-01-01 06:10:00    19.383795
2015-01-01 06:11:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:12:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:13:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:14:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:15:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:16:00    26.530258
2015-01-01 06:17:00    27.868579
2015-01-01 06:18:00    29.320614
2015-01-01 06:19:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:20:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:21:00    NaN
2015-01-01 06:22:00    35.854773
2015-01-01 06:23:00    37.639202
2015-01-01 06:24:00    39.406136
```

Then I want a histogram with 1 occurrence of 1 a minute hole, 2 occurrences of a 3 minute hole, and 1 occurrence of a 5 minute hole.

In my data, NaN intervals are much larger, so maybe I would like to measure their length in hours or days.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Generally, a question is indicated by ending a sentence with a question mark, “?”, and typically includes an explicit interrogative like “How do I…” or “What is the…” If you are asking for somebody to write the code to do what you want, that is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. If you are having a problem with a specific part of the task, you should specify what problem you are having–what do you not understand, what specific function do you need, and so on.

Comment: Edited the title. Sorry I wasn't able to add code, I'm at a lost here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': [1, np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, 3, 2, 3, 4, np.NaN],
               'feature2': [4, np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, 4, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN]})

def foo(start,stop,df,feat):
    counts = df.loc[start:stop,feat].value_counts(dropna=False)
    counts.plot.bar(grid=True)
    plt.show()

foo(3,8,df,'feature2')
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. I edited the question so maybe it's more clear. Thanks!